# How to make two existing counters truly synchronized?

Tags: macros, counters

In my document, there is an object that should share the same counter (value) with `section`, that is, when the counter `section` gets changed, it should change accordingly, and vice versa. I did this by setting `\c@...` and `\the...` to be the same as those of `section`.

However, with this method, when my custom counter changes its value (the value of `section` does get changed accordingly), sub-counters numbered within `section` (such as `subsection`) are not being reset.

For example, in the following MWE, I expect the second subsection to be numbered `1.1` instead of `1.2` (*`\stepcounter{testcounter}` already changes the value of the counter `section`, however, unlike with `\stepcounter{section}`, the sub-counter `subsection` is not being reset here*).

How should this be achieved?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{testcounter}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \mymodule_counter_alias:nn
  {
    \cs_set_eq:cc { c@ #1 } { c@ #2 }
    \cs_set_eq:cc { the #1 } { the #2 }
  }

\mymodule_counter_alias:nn { testcounter } { section }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\subsection{Test}

\stepcounter{testcounter} % 1.2
% \stepcounter{section}   % 1.1

\subsection{Test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your objective. E.g., should the counters `section` and `testcounter` share the same underlying counter variable, so that whenever one counter is incremented the other gets incremented as well? Or should the counter variable `testcounter` be "slaved" [sorry, not my term/jargon] to the `section` counter variable?

Comment: @Mico I'm not sure how to express this accurately. In short word, I need them to have separate counter names, but in addition to behave exactly the same (i.e. when one changes, another changes accordingly, and all the sub-counters should be reset).

Comment: @Mico I'm aware of things like `aliascnt`. However, it does not work for existed counters, one has to define one of the counters with `\newaliascnt`.

Comment: I think to get what you want, you'd be looking for `\cs_set_eq:cc { cl@ #1 } { cl@ #2 }`. But I would recommend you don't do it (specially if you intend to include this in a package). As far as I can tell, there's a general presumption that a given counter is only reset by one other, and that would give you two. (I don't know `aliascnt` works, though). Besides, even that wouldn't give you a full aliasing, you still don't know which counter resets `section` there, and it would be some work to find out and alias the upper levels of the resetting chain too.

Comment: @gusbrs Thank you, `\cs_set_eq:cc { cl@ #1 } { cl@ #2 }` works fine in my document. Could you please explain in more detail what might go wrong with this method? The result seems quite good to me and I'm really considering modifying the  `\..._counter_alias:nn` function in my package with this additional line. (You can make this an answer. To be honest I never heard of this internal `\cl@...` before.)

Comment: @Jinwen the `\cl@<counter>` macro stores a list of the counters `<counter>` resets. Take a look at the `\newcounter` machinery, and `\@addtoreset` in particular. What can go wrong is that the counter machinery has pretty hard-coded that only one counter resets another so, if you break that expectation, you might be in for some fun. And, no, I don't intend to have this as an answer, as I've said, I don't recommend it.

Comment: Furthermore, as I've also argued previously, this is still not sufficient for the two counters to behave the same way. For example, if, in the book class, you step `chapter`, `section` will be reset, but `testcounter` won't.

Comment: I don't think that's really possible. Assume that the infrastructure belonging to the counter `foo` is the same as that belonging to the counter `bar`. E.g. by means of `\let\c@foo=\c@bar` and `\let\cl@foo=\cl@bar` and `\let\p@foo=\p@bar` etc. If `\@addtoreset{foo}{baz}` is executed, then the counter `foo` is set to 0 whenever `baz` is incremented, but the counter `bar` is not set to 0 when `baz` is incremented.  You would have to change all macros that adjust the infrastructure of a counter so that they always do what is done with `foo` as counter argument also with `bar` and vice versa.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Thank you for the explanation, may I ask what is `\p@...` for?

Comment: `\p@...` denotes "prefix" with cross-referencing-labels. E.g., if you have a counter "foo" and you do `\def\p@foo{Prefix}` and `\def\thefoo{\arabic{foo}}` and via `\label` place a cross-referencing-label right after stepping `foo` via `\refstepcounter` so that it has the value 17, then cross-referencing that label via `\ref` yields the text-phrase "Prefix17". More about infrastructure of counters can be found in [source2e.pdf, file s:ltcounts.dtx, section 1.1 Environment Counter Macros](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf#subsection.19.1.1)